# Can't get background image to work on stacklayout

Tags: css, angular, image, typescript, nativescript

I've got a JSON file returning any number of images as base64. In my component.html, I'm trying to set the images as the background to a StackLayout like so:

```
<StackLayout height="200" *ngFor="let image of selectedProperty.images">
   <StackLayout height="100%" ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+image.base64+')'}"></StackLayout>
   <!--<Image src="{{ image.base64 }}"></Image>-->
</StackLayout>
```

I know that `image.base64` holds the correct base64 strings, because if I uncomment the `<Image>` element, it displays the images fine. It seems like the issue is the `background-image` css property itself, because even if I try to do it using a normal image from google (for example `style="background-image:url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/839721704163155970/LI_TRk1z_400x400.jpg')"`
), it doesn't work either. I'm feeling extremely silly because this just *has* to be something very simple, but I just cannot figure it out.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think NS supports the standard url() syntax. instead of ng-style=.... try  backgroundImage="{{ image.base64 }}"

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing in one of my projects. I set a div to be hidden until the image has loaded. To track this event, I am listening to the `load` event on the `img` tag.

```
<!-- the div is hidden until the image is loaded -->
<div *ngIf="photo.url" class="image" [hidden]="loading"
     [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + photo.url + ')'}" >
</div>
<!-- hidden img tag to load the image and toggle loading status -->
<img src="{{photo.url}}" alt="{{photo.description}} photo" hidden (load)="imageLoaded()">
```

And in the controller:

```
imageLoaded() {
  this.loading = false;
}
```

So when browser fetches is ready to render the image, the event handler sets `loading` to be `false`, which updates the view, and the `<div>` is not hidden anymore, which causes it to render.

I assume you can adapt the code to use NativeScript, but tell me if not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I've attempted using a similar NativeScript solution, but the result is the same -- all I'm getting is empty StackLayouts. This is really very confusing haha